# Battery Drainage Issue with the Android application

Tags: android-studio, battery

I have an issue with the battery drainage related to my application. My application is running as a background service and is required to get the location updates every 20 seconds. Additionally, it also uses Wifi Direct.

I am unable to fix the battery drainage issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your android app can't control the usage upon the services usage (upon permission-request usage) but you can optimize your code to run smooth your application. maybe it is on your phone's preference since you are using location servies and runtime background :)